# Github Actions doesn't get triggered on release creation

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-ci

I have github actions workflow which should be triggered on release creation

```yaml
name: "Attach package to release assets"

# https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
```

and another workflow which is responsible for release creation and should trigger this event (and workflow)

```yaml
      - name: Create release
        uses: thomaseizinger/create-release@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          target_commitish: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merge_commit_sha }}
          tag_name: ${{ env.RELEASE_VERSION }}
          name: ${{ env.RELEASE_VERSION }}
          body: ${{ steps.changelog_reader.outputs.changes }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

There is a release created on Github, so this action works properly. My question is how to debug events and see why first workflow is not invoked. I've tried already `published` and `released` without any effect.

Comment: Triggering a workflow from another workflow event requires using a `PAT` instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`. Did you try using a PAT instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`?

Comment: I think the GitHub `release` event may actually be broken in workflows. I've been trying to do the same thing without the programmatic trigger (just `on: [release]`) and it never fires but I can confirm the event is indeed happening. Seems like a platform bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow)

> For example, if a workflow run pushes code using the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, a new workflow **WILL NOT RUN** even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

See [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) to create a custom token